# Is the size of the set of injections from a set to another is bigger than the size of the second one?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Specifically, consider the set $X:=\{f:{M_1\times...\times M_n}\to B|f \,\,{\rm is}\,\, 1-1\}$, where all of the sets involved are at least $\aleph_0$ in size. Is $|X|>|B|$?

Comment: $X$ could be empty - what if $\vert M_1\vert>\vert B\vert$?

Comment: Not necessarily even if $|M_1\times\ldots\times M_n|\le|B|$: the set of $X$ of injections from $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb R$ is the same as the cardinality of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Do you mean $<$?

Comment: @Noah: I did indeed, though $\le$ is actually a better response following your comment.

Comment: Thanks! What if the size of all sets involved is $\aleph_0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\vert M_1\times ...\times M_n\vert=\max\{\vert M_1\vert,...,\vert M_n\vert\}$ (all sets involved being infinite), we can just consider a single $M$:

> Given infinite sets $M,B$, what can we say about the cardinality of the set $X$ of injections from $M$ to $B$?

There is one trivial case, one easy cases, and then the remaining case is surprisingly complicated.

The trivial case is if $\vert M\vert>\vert B\vert$. Then of course $X=\emptyset$.

The easy case is if $\vert M\vert=\vert B\vert$. It's a standard exercise that the set of self-bijections of an infinite set has the same cardinality as the set of subsets of that set, so now $\vert X\vert=2^{\vert B\vert}$.

Now we're left with the case $\vert M\vert<\vert B\vert$. At this point it's useful to prove the following: if $A,B$ are infinite sets with $\vert A\vert\le\vert B\vert$, there are as many injections from $A$ to $B$ as there are functions from $A$ to $B$ altogether. (This is a good exercise if you haven't seen it before.) So basically we're now just asking:

> Suppose $\kappa<\lambda$ are infinite cardinals. What can we say about $\lambda^\kappa$ (= the cardinality of the set of functions from a set of size $\kappa$ to a set of size $\lambda$)?

While "nice" examples tend to be boring (= come out to just $\lambda$ itself), in generality things suddenly explode. Cardinal exponentiation is surprisingly nuanced. For one thing, many (in fact the vast majority of) basic questions about it are undecidable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$. One of the few things [we **can** prove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)#K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_and_cofinality) is a connection with cofinality: for all infinite $\alpha$ we have $\alpha^{cf(\alpha)}>\alpha$. So, for example, we could have $M=\mathbb{N}$ and $B$ be "very uncountable" but still have $\vert X\vert>\vert B\vert$.

(Of course I've tacitly applied choice several times in the above. Cardinal arithmetic becomes hideous without choice.)

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but in the second case do you mean self-injections?

Comment: @Ak9 Nope, although that's true too - I stated the fact for self-bijections because that's a stronger result.